# GWT replace-with code

Tags: gwt, gwt-validation

related to a previous un-answered question of myself: how can i find the code that will be executed when i use

```
<replace-with class="xxxxxx.xxxxxx.BeanValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

I suspect it may be causing an unexpected behaviour when the ValidatorFactory is used somewhere else but the client and i wonder if having an eye on the code can point me to a workaround/solution.

Thx!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What problem do you suspect that this causes? The code that does the replacing is inside the compiler, not something you should typically need to review. Or are you asking where is this replacement done?

Comment: Hi Colin, thx for the answer. The actual problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527328/gwt-validator-factory-class-loading-issue   My suspect is that somehow this could be executed at the server-side and causing a replacement of the default HibernateValidator ... i even configured my custom validator provider and just sometimes it is ignored in favor of the GWT client-side class

Comment: These can never be executed on the server - they are directives to the GWT compile to replace any call to `GWT.create(SomeClass.class)` with a call to a specific subclass.

Comment: to be honest that's what i thought, but i am kinda desperate with the thing ... like i said, even creating my own custom validator providers, this client-side class comes out in action at the server-side from time to time (randomly causing server failure). Thx Colin, gonna have to keep on searching somewhere else